# Como fazer uma coluna com dados sempre fixos em um DataTable? MVC JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvc, datatable

Olá. Tenho um DataTable que está retornando valores do BD, porém eu preciso de que apenas uma coluna sempre tenha valores fixos que não virão do BD (no caso, é uma coluna com os meses do ano). Porém, não posso alterar a estrutura do DataTable diretamente no HTML pois estou o construindo da seguinte forma:

```js
    var colsBaseLT = [
    { data: null, className: 'col-sm-2 text-center', title: 'Base Hour', defaultContent: ''},
    { data: 'Quantity', className: 'col-sm-2 text-center', title: 'Quantidade', defaultContent: ''},
    { data: 'Year', className: 'col-sm-2 text-center', title: 'Ano', defaultContent: ''},
];

function CreateTable() {
    DataTablesAjaxPagination("#tableBaseHour", colsBaseLT, null, null, 12, 'BaseHour');
    $.ajax({
        url: urlCreateTable,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
            dataTableBH = DataTablesAjaxScrollHeight('#tableBaseHour', colsBaseLT, result.Grid, null, "350px");
        }
    });
}
```

Na primeira coluna, a Base Hour, quero que haja 12 linhas pré-definidas com os meses do ano em cada. Já tentei usar o `table.row.add`, mas como a DataTable está inicializando pelo método Pagination acabei não conseguindo com que as linhas sejam criadas com os valores que eu colocasse.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

EDIT: Consegui fazer o DataTable mostrar a lista dos Meses, porém ele mostra a lista toda num campo só! Como faço para que cada mês apareça num campo de uma linha diferente?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public DataTable Export(BMContext perRequestInstance){

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Rule");

        return dt;
    }
```

acho que pode ajudar.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que meu projeto precisava cara, muito obrigado!!!!!